# How to integrate two applications as a single application

Tags: iphone, composition

Hi,

I am new to iPhone. I created two separate applications. What I want to do now is integrate the two applications into one. For example, I could show two buttons and clicking the first takes the user to the first application, while clicking the second button takes the user to the second application.

How should I approach this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and generic way to do what you ask is to create two independent RootViewcontrollers and manage their appearence in the AppDelegate of the new app with `presentModalViewController:animated:`. Each controller shall encapsulate what a single application was doing before, acting as its on appDelegate (and so maybe you need to declare it accessible globally if one application was accessing its appDelegate from many classes).
Another way is to use a UITabBarController that will wrap the two RootViewControllers.

Comment: Here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1 you can find something about using UITabBarControllers